# How to properly close a pipe

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I have a piece of code I am trying to alter. The code is simply 2 pipes that communicate between two processes (parent and child process). I am trying to create a "clean termination" of the program so that whenever a 0 is sent from parent to the child the respective process shuts down their end of all pipes.

The code is something like:

```
int main
{
   int pipe1[2], pipe2[2], value, request;
   if(pipe(pipe1) < 0 || pipe(pipe2) < 0)
        printf("Failed to create pipes.\n");

   switch(fork())
   {
       case -1:
            perror("Cannot create fork.\n");
            break;

       case 0:
           close (pipe1[WRITE]);
           close (pipe2[READ]);
           close (0);
           close (1);

         for(;;) {
           read(pipe1[READ], &value, sizeof value);

           //If user enters 0.
           if(value == 0)
           {
               printf("Terminating child process!\n");
               close(pipe1[READ]);
               //write a 0 back to the parent so that it can close its end.
               write(pipe2[WRITE], 0, sizeof (int));
               close(pipe2[WRITE]);
               exit(0);
           }
           else
           {
               /*Enter function to do something on the number here*/
               write(pipe2[WRITE], &result, sizeof result);
           }
        }
        break;

        default: /* PARENT PROCESS - PRODUCER */
             close(pipe1[READ]);
             close(pipe2[WRITE]);
             for(;;) {
                 printf("Ange ett tal: ");
                 scanf("%d", &value);
                 if(write(pipe1[WRITE], &value, sizeof value) != sizeof value)
                 {
                     perror("Cannot write thru pipe.\n");
                     return 1;
                 }

             //Clean shutdown if value == 0
              if(value == 0)
             {
                 close(pipe2[WRITE]);
                 read(pipe2[READ],&result,sizeof(result));
                 if(result == 0)
                 {
                     close(pipe2[READ]);
                     printf("Pipe2[Read] closed!\n");
                     wait(0);
                 }
             }

             else
             {
                 read(pipe2[READ],&result,sizeof(result));
                 printf("Result: %d.\n",result);
             }

     }
     break;
  }


}
```

I have been at this for hours now and I do not understand why my code is acting all crazy. When I enter `1` it says "Pipe closed and if i enter `0` it tries to accept another input before giving an error `Cannot create pipes!`.

I think I am missing something very fundamental here. Any help on the subject is very much appreciated.

Comment: Where are you creating the pipes? Your `if` statement is checking the value of the pipe contents, but you never called `pipe()`.

Comment: And pipes should always be a 2-element array, why do you have `int pipe1[1]`?

Comment: Also...return codes are your friend - use them.

Comment: I editted the code. I had troubles copy pasting the code so had to re-write most of the code. The typos have been fixed (I think). @Duck Return codes of what? Im new at programming so please be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the key change!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

enum { READ = 0, WRITE = 1 };

int main(void)
{
    int pipe1[2], pipe2[2], value, result;
    if (pipe(pipe1) < 0 || pipe(pipe2) < 0)
        printf("Failed to create pipes.\n");

    switch (fork())
    {
    case -1:
        perror("Cannot create fork.\n");
        break;

    case 0:
        close(pipe1[WRITE]);
        close(pipe2[READ]);

        while (read(pipe1[READ], &value, sizeof(value)) > 0)
        {
            // If user enters 0.
            if (value == 0)
            {
                printf("Terminating child process!\n");
                close(pipe1[READ]);
                // write a 0 back to the parent so that it can close its end.
                write(pipe2[WRITE], 0, sizeof(int));
                close(pipe2[WRITE]);
                exit(0);
            }
            else
            {
                result = value + 1;
                write(pipe2[WRITE], &result, sizeof result);
            }
        }
        break;

    default:     /* PARENT PROCESS - PRODUCER */
        close(pipe1[READ]);
        close(pipe2[WRITE]);
        for ( ; ; )
        {
            printf("Ange ett tal: ");
            if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1)
                break;
            if (write(pipe1[WRITE], &value, sizeof(value)) != sizeof(value))
            {
                perror("Cannot write thru pipe.\n");
                return 1;
            }
            // Clean shutdown if value == 0
            if (value == 0)
            {
                close(pipe1[WRITE]);    // Key change!
                if (read(pipe2[READ], &result, sizeof(result)) <= 0 || result == 0)
                {
                    close(pipe2[READ]);
                    printf("Pipe2[Read] closed!\n");
                    wait(0);
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (read(pipe2[READ], &result, sizeof(result)) <= 0)
                    break;
                printf("Result: %d.\n", result);
                if (result == 0)
                {
                    printf("Read zero - exit\n");
                    close(pipe1[WRITE]);
                    close(pipe2[READ]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jonathan, the solution did indeed solve the problem. However I want to understand everything so I'll ask some follow up questions. First of all you made a condition `if (read(pipe2[READ], &result, sizeof(result)) <= 0 || result == 0)` which reads the file descriptor and in the same statement made a check if the result was `0`. Then in the `else` statement right underneath you have another `if (result == 0). What is the purpose of that?

Comment: Always check your read operations.  Arguably, the test should be `if (read(pipe2[READ], &result, sizeof(result)) != sizeof(result) || result == 0)`, but what I wrote is reasonably safe.  It checks whether the read works, and if the read worked, whether the result was zero.  Both are reasons to terminate, I believe.  With the `result = value + 1;` 'function', if you type -1, the code exits; if you type 0, the code exits; otherwise, the code continues.  The check on `scanf()` is crucial; if you type 'a' instead of a number and don't test `scanf()`, your program will run a long time.  Etc.

Comment: Incidentally, the code should report errors to standard error and exit or return if either `pipe()` call fails.