# Which pipes do I need to close per process in a Unix pipeline with multiple pipes?

Tags: unix, pipe, pipeline

In my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77544736/10824322) to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9834086/10824322), I decided to implement the pipeline

```
git log --format='%an' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 3
```

I'm pasting it here for reference:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    pid_t git_pid, sort_pid1, sort_pid2, uniq_pid, head_pid;

    int pipefd1[2];
    int pipefd2[2];
    int pipefd3[2];
    int pipefd4[2];

    pipe(pipefd1);
    pipe(pipefd2);
    pipe(pipefd3);
    pipe(pipefd4);

    if ((git_pid = fork()) == 0) {
        dup2(pipefd1[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

        close(pipefd1[1]);
        close(pipefd1[0]);

        if (execlp("git", "git", "log", "--format=%an", (char *) NULL) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed trying to execute the git command");
            exit(0);
        };
    }
    else if (git_pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed forking git process");
    }

    if ((sort_pid1 = fork()) == 0) {
        dup2(pipefd1[0], STDIN_FILENO); 
        dup2(pipefd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO); 
 
        close(pipefd1[0]);
        close(pipefd1[1]);
        close(pipefd2[1]);
        close(pipefd2[0]);

        if (execlp("sort", "sort", (char *) NULL) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed trying to execute the sort command");
            exit(0);
        };
    }
    else if (sort_pid1 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed forking sort process");
        exit(0);
    }

    if ((uniq_pid = fork()) == 0) {
        dup2(pipefd2[0], STDIN_FILENO); 
        dup2(pipefd3[1], STDOUT_FILENO); 

        close(pipefd1[0]);
        close(pipefd1[1]);
        close(pipefd2[0]);
        close(pipefd2[1]);
        close(pipefd3[0]);
        close(pipefd3[1]);

        if (execlp("uniq", "uniq", "-c", (char *) NULL) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed trying to execute the uniq command");
            exit(0);
        };
    }
    else if (sort_pid1 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed forking uniq process");
        exit(0);
    }

    if ((sort_pid2 = fork()) == 0) {
        dup2(pipefd3[0], STDIN_FILENO); 
        dup2(pipefd4[1], STDOUT_FILENO); 

        close(pipefd1[0]);
        close(pipefd1[1]);
        close(pipefd2[0]);
        close(pipefd2[1]);
        close(pipefd3[0]);
        close(pipefd3[1]);
        close(pipefd4[0]);
        close(pipefd4[1]);

        if (execlp("sort", "sort", "-nr", (char *) NULL) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed trying to execute the sort command");
            exit(0);
        };
    }
    else if (sort_pid2 < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed forking sort process");
        exit(0);
    }

    if ((head_pid = fork()) == 0) {
        dup2(pipefd4[0], STDIN_FILENO); 

        close(pipefd1[0]);
        close(pipefd1[1]);
        close(pipefd2[0]);
        close(pipefd2[1]);
        close(pipefd3[0]);
        close(pipefd3[1]);
        close(pipefd4[0]);
        close(pipefd4[1]);

        if (execlp("head", "head", "-n", "3", (char *) NULL) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed trying to execute the head command");
            exit(0);
        };
    }
    else if (head_pid < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed forking head process");
        exit(0);
    }

    close(pipefd1[0]);
    close(pipefd1[1]);
    close(pipefd2[0]);
    close(pipefd2[1]);
    close(pipefd3[0]);
    close(pipefd3[1]);
    close(pipefd4[0]);
    close(pipefd4[1]);

    int git_status, sort1_status, sort2_status, uniq_status, head_status;
    pid_t git_wpid = waitpid(git_pid, &git_status, 0);
    pid_t sort1_wpid = waitpid(sort_pid1, &sort1_status, 0);
    pid_t sort2_wpid = waitpid(sort_pid2, &sort2_status, 0);
    pid_t uniq_wpid = waitpid(uniq_pid, &uniq_status, 0);
    pid_t head_wpid = waitpid(head_pid, &head_status, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

**Question:** Why do I need to progressively close more pipes as the program goes long, even if they aren't used by the process? This leads to the question in the title: Which pipes do I need to close per process in a Unix pipeline with multiple pipes?

For example, for the `git_pid` process I close only `pipefd1`, however for the `uniq_pid` process I need to close `pipedf1` even if the process isn't using that pipe. It's the same case for `sort_pid2` where I need to close `pipefd1` and `pipefd2` and `head_pid` where I need to close `pipefd1`, `pipedf2`, and `pipefd3`.

I found some related questions but none of them answers my question:

- [Unix Pipes - Pipeline between three processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056084/unix-pipes-pipeline-between-three-processes)
- [When and why do I have to close pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584034/when-and-why-do-i-have-to-close-pipe)
- [When piping, why do you have to close() the opposite end of a pipe before using dup2()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29067335/when-piping-why-do-you-have-to-close-the-opposite-end-of-a-pipe-before-using)
- [How to properly close a pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21471602/how-to-properly-close-a-pipe)
- [Why should you close a pipe in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265191/why-should-you-close-a-pipe-in-linux)

Comment: Ask yourself this question: How does a process reading a pipe know that no more data will be sent? How does it detect EOF?